# Difference between datetime across multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I need to calculate the average time difference between the customer first booking and second booking.  In source table a customer can have one or more bookings.  The table shows 3 unique customers and what time each booking was created.

I produced this table with the following query

```
select b.customer_id, b.time_created
from booking b
order by b.customer_id
```

**Customer bookings**

| customer_id | time_created |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 2021-05-15 10:00:00:000 |
| 32 | 2021-05-24 10:00:00:000 |
| 59 | 2021-05-27 14:00:00:000 |
| 71 | 2021-06-04 15:00:00:000 |
| 71 | 2021-06-05 17:00:00:000 |
| 71 | 2021-06-06 18:00:00:000 |

**Desired output**

| customer_id | datetime_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | diff 2021-05-24 10:00:00:000 - 2021-05-15 10:00:00:000) |
| 59 | - |
| 71 | (2021-06-05 17:00:00:000 - 2021-06-04 15:00:00:000) |

**Update**

| customer_id | datetime_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 100 | 55455498365000 |
| 10005 | 934039000000 |
| 10011 | 120000 |
| 10044 | 634051554000 |
| 10053 | 516000000 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  One method:

```
select customer_id,
       max(time_created) - nullif(min(time_created), max(time_created)) as time_diff
from (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by time_created) as seqnum
      from booking b
     ) b
where seqnum <= 2
group by customer_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5342a5219813cf70b7b81241429cbfa7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I get an error ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist

Comment: @James Use your real table name: `from booking t`.

Comment: okay thanks, got data coming back now but the time_diff is a number, can it be converted to human readable?

Comment: @James . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  You can format the results however you like.

Comment: Im not completely sure what this sql is doing.  But is this the difference between the first and second booking for each specific customer_id

Comment: @James . . . Yes.  This is enumerating the rows per customer, filtering to the first two, and then taking the difference per customer.

Comment: ok, let me convert the column to a human readable value and run some tests on it!  thanks

Comment: I don't understand!  If I take a value from the query (example: 55455498365000) and paste it into https://www.epochconverter.com/ it gives me a date?  I need to see how days/ hours/ minutes are between the first and second booking?

Comment: @James . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The results look fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, it looks like it's exactly what I need.  I've updated my question with an update with what I see from the query output